# How do I make a PHP POST Request to TheGraph API?

Tags: php, graphql

I want to make a PHP POST request to "The Graph" API. I've been unable to find an example of this.

For instance, how would I convert the example query for Polymarket into a PHP POST request?
https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/tokenunion/polymarket-matic?selected=playground

```
{
  globals(first: 5) {
    id
    numConditions
    numOpenConditions
    numClosedConditions
  }
  accounts(first: 5) {
    id
    creationTimestamp
    lastSeenTimestamp
    collateralVolume
  }
}
```

So far I have

```
    $sUrl="https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/tokenunion/polymarket-matic";
    $query="query {
    globals(first: 5) {
      id
      numConditions
      numOpenConditions
      numClosedConditions
    }
    accounts(first: 5) {
      id
      creationTimestamp
      lastSeenTimestamp
      collateralVolume
    }
}";

    $aData=array('query' => $query);
    
    $options = array(
            'https' => array(
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query($aData)
            )
    );
    
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($sUrl, false, $context);
    var_dump($result);
```

And this just returns a GraphiQL example.

Comment: This PHP example works. But I'm unable to get any request to work with Polymarket.
https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/01/14/GraphQL-via-HTTP-in-five-ways/

Comment: try with Postman first - auth reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.  Maybe a syntax issue?  But I found another example and was able to modify it to work.  So this works (returns a list of polymarket trades for a user, from 2020, with a limit of 1000):

```
$sUrl="https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/tokenunion/polymarket-matic";

$sStartdate='2020/01/01';
$sEnddate='2020/12/31';

$iStarttime=strtotime($sStartdate);
$iEndtime=strtotime($sEnddate);
$sUser="0xf449b747376a2036dd76ada1484e0a2389c8d43b";

$sGraph='{"query":"{transactions(where: {user:\"'.$sUser.'\"  timestamp_gte: '.$iStarttime.' timestamp_lte: '.$iEndtime.'} orderBy: timestamp orderDirection: asc first:1000) {id, type, timestamp, market {id}, tradeAmount, feeAmount, outcomeIndex, outcomeTokensAmount}}"}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $sGraph); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$aData=json_decode($data);
print_r ($aData);
```